# SQL calculate the total cost of raw materials for each finish product

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hey i am trying to answer this question

Compose a query to calculate the total cost of raw materials for each finish product. In the result table, we would like to see Product ID, Product Name, and its total cost of raw materials. Sort the results by the total cost of raw materials in descending order.

This is what i have

```
SELECT Product_t.Product_ID, Product_t.Product_Name, SUM(Uses_t.Footage * Raw_Materials_t.Unit_price ) AS Total_Cost_Of_Raw_Materials
FROM Product_t, Uses_t, Raw_materials_t
WHERE Product_t.Product_ID=Uses_t.Product_ID and  Uses_t.Material_ID=Raw_materials_t.Material_ID
GROUP BY Product_ID
ORDER BY SUM(Raw_Materials_t.Unit_price * Uses_t.Footage) DESC;
```

The error pops up that The specified field Product_ID could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

I thought i fixed that but clearly its not working 
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: how can i join 3 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access is a lousy database to use if you are learning SQL.  It has peculiarities.  I think the query would look like this:

```
SELECT p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name,
       SUM(u.Footage * m.Unit_price) AS Total_Cost_Of_Raw_Materials
FROM (Product_t as p INNER JOIN
      Uses_t as u
      ON p.Product_ID = u.Product_ID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Raw_materials_t as m
     ON u.Material_ID = m.Material_ID
GROUP BY p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name, 
ORDER BY SUM(m.Unit_price * u.Footage) DESC;
```

Comment: It asks me to enter a parameter. i have the unit price already in materials_t

Comment: @AdrianZdanowski . . . If you have a choice of databases, almost anything else is closer to ANSI standards -- Postgres, SQL Server Express, Oracle Express, MySQL,for instance.